# Image of a dense set through unbounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $T$ be a densely defined, closed operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $T^*T$ remains densely defined. Obviously, $\sigma(I+T^*T)\subset [1,\infty)$, which in particular implies this operator (is surjective and) has a bounded inverse $A$.

Now, what I'm wondering is: If we let $\mathcal{D}$ be a dense/total subset of $H$ which sits inside the domain of $I+T^*T$, does it follow that $(I+T^*T)(\mathcal{D})$ remains a dense/total subset?

It seems very plausible, given how ``close'' this operator is to being bounded and invertible; however, I cannot find a proof of this.

A proof of counterexample would be most welcome.

Comment: Could you briefly explain why $\sigma(I+T^*T)\subset[1,\infty)$?

Comment: $T^*T$ is self adjoint and positive, so its spectrum is on the positive half-line; adding an identity, we get it from $1$ onwards. I may be slightly wrong, but the important bit of spectral theory I want here is that $I+T^*T$ is an invertible operator - and that, I  believe, is certainly the case?

Comment: But why is $T^*T$ positive? I believe it, and maybe I'm just being daft, but can't see why it's "obvious".

Comment: Isn't every operator of the form $T^*T$ positive by definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is false.

It is always the case that $T^{\star}T$ is densely-defined and selfadjoint if $T$ is a closed densely-defined linear operator on a Hilbert Space $H$.

Let $H=L^2[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal{AC}[0,1]$ be the absolutely continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Define $T=\frac{d}{dt}$ on the domain
$$
    \mathcal{D}(T)=\{ f \in \mathcal{AC}[0,1] : f'\in L^2[0,1],\;\; f(0)=0 \}.
$$
Then $T^{\star}=-\frac{d}{dt}$ on the domain
$$
    \mathcal{D}(T^{\star})=\{ f \in \mathcal{AC}[0,1] : f' \in L^2[0,1],\;\; f(1)=0 \}.
$$
This basically follows because $(f',g)-(f,g')=f\overline{g}|_{0}^{1}$.

The operator $T^{\star}T$ has a domain $\mathcal{D}(T^{\star}T)$ consisting of all $f \in \mathcal{AC}^2[0,1]$ (twice absolutely continuous functions) for which $f(0)=f'(1)=0$.

Define a new operator $S$ as the restriction of $T^{\star}T$ to
$$
          \mathcal{D}(S) = \{ f\in\mathcal{D}(T^{\star}T) : f(0)=f'(0)=f(1)=f'(1)=0 \}.
$$
Then $S$ is a closed operator, and the domain is dense in $H$ because the subspace $\mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(0,1)$ of compactly supported infinitely-differentiable functions is dense in $H$ and contained in $\mathcal{D}(S)$. Because of the endpoint conditions, integration by parts gives
$$
       (Sf,e^{t})=(-f'',e^{t})=-(f,e^{t}),\;\;\; f\in\mathcal{D}(S) \\
         ((I+T^{\star}T)f,e^{t})=0,\;\;\;f \in \mathcal{D}(S).
$$
Therefore $(I+T^{\star}T)\mathcal{D}(S)$ cannot be dense in $H$ even though $\mathcal{D}(S)\subset \mathcal{D}(T^{\star}T)$ is dense in $H$.

Comment: Thank you! Your example works through some fancy domain work - I am wondering if defining $T$ on some sort of ``maximal domain'' would work, but I cannot formalise that notion...

Comment: @Confusio : A restriction of $I+T^{\star}T$ to a subspace $\mathcal{D}$ has a dense range iff $S=I+T^{\star}T$ on $\mathcal{D}(S)=\mathcal{D}$ is essentially selfadjoint, meaning that the closure of $S$ is selfadjoint. This is because $(Sx,x) \ge \|x\|^2$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}$. In fact, the closure of such an $S$ with dense range will always be $I+T^{\star}T$.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Could you explain why $(Sx,x)\ge\|x\|^2$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}$ implies that the range of $S$ is dense?

Comment: @MartinWiebusch : $\|x\|^2 \le \|Sx\|\|x\| \implies \|Sx\| \ge \|x\|$. So if $y$ is in the closure of the range, then there is a sequence $\{ x_n \}$ such that $\{ Sx_n \}$ converges to $y$. The inequality forces $\{ x_n \}$ to be Cauchy and, hence, convergent to some $x_0$, and then $Sx_0 = y$.

Comment: But we want to show that the closure of the range is the entire space $H$, right? How does constructing $x_0$ help with that? Doesn't this just show that the range of $S$ is closed?

Comment: @MartinWiebusch : I was answering a question in the comment above about why $(Sx,x) \ge \|x\|^2$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}$ forces the range of $S$ to be closed if the operator $S$ is closed. The operator $S$ I construct in the post definitely does not have a dense range, which is what needs to happen in order for the operator to not be selfadjoint or to have a closure that is selfadjoint.

Comment: @MartinWiebusch : I was answering the OP in the negative. The answer to his question is "No." There are examples where $(I+T^*T)\mathcal{D}$ is not dense even though $\mathcal{D}$ is dense.

Comment: @TrialAndError: My question was about your comment from 2016-01-31. You state that a restriction of $I+T^*T$ to a domain $\mathcal{D}$ *does* have dense range if this restriction is essentially self-adjoint. You say that this is because $(Sx,x)\geq\|x\|^2$ for all $x\in\mathcal{D}$ but I'm struggling to follow that argument. As far as I can tell your comment from 2016-11-04 only shows that the range is closed. (Sorry if I'm being dense here.)

Comment: @MartinWiebusch : Here's another approach. Let $S$ be the restriction of $I+T^*T$ to a domain $\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{D}(I+T^*T)$ which is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. Let $\overline{S}$ be the closure of $S$. Then $\mathcal{R}(\overline{S})$ is closed because of the inequality $\|\overline{S}x\|\ge \|x\|$ which must hold because it holds for $I+T^*T$ and $\overline{S}$ has $I+T^*T$ as an extension. If $\overline{S}$ is selfadjoint, then $\mathcal{R}(\overline{S})=\overline{\mathcal{R}(\overline{S})}=\mathcal{N}(\overline{S})^{\perp}=\{0\}^{\perp}=\mathcal{H}$.